# How do i get data from a txt file and send it to excel spreadsheet?(I only want everything after the ":" in the txt file)?

Tags: java, excel

I have a program (below) that takes txt files and puts them into an excel spreadsheet. My goal is to extract the data from a text file but only text after the colon.

Example txt file(No space between "name:" and "phone:" lines in the txt):

Name: John doe

phone: (xxx) xxx-xxxx

I want my program to only save john doe in the excel sheet and title the column "Name":
I want my program to only save (xxx) xxx-xxxx in the excel sheet and title the column "phone" 
I want to be able to add multiple entrys to the spreadsheet.

Example(in excel sheet generated):This is what i want it to look like!

....A..............B

1   name     | Phone

2   john doe   (123) 123-1234

3   jack dee   (123) 123-1231

So i looked at the string split to get only data after the ":" but cant find much documentation on it. Also getting the info to line up correctly in the excel. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
James

```
package EREW;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRichTextString;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;


public class ReadWriteXL
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException{
    ArrayList arr=new ArrayList();
File f=new File("F:\\temp\\TEXT\\email.txt");

Scanner in=new Scanner(f);
System.out.println("Read Data From The Txt file ");
while(in.hasNext())
{    

arr.add(in.nextLine());
}
System.out.println("Data From ArrayList");
System.out.println(arr);


System.out.println("Write data to an Excel Sheet");
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("F:/temp/1.xls");
HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet spreadSheet = workBook.createSheet("email");
HSSFRow row;
HSSFCell cell;
for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
    row = spreadSheet.createRow((short) i);
cell = row.createCell(i);
System.out.println(arr.get(i));
cell.setCellValue(arr.get(i).toString());
}
System.out.println("Done");
workBook.write(fos);
arr.clear();
System.out.println("ReadIng From Excel Sheet");

FileInputStream fis = null;
    fis = new FileInputStream("F:/temp/1.xls");

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        HSSFRow row1 = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
        Iterator cells = row1.cellIterator();
        while (cells.hasNext()) {
            HSSFCell cell1 = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
            arr.add(cell1);
        }
}
System.out.println(arr);

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file `email.txt` Always has the format you said:

```
Name: John
phone: (xxx) xxx-xxxx
```

I'm not familiarized with the row and cell creation, so I will give you some pseudo code to you understand what you have to do on your code:

On this part of your code:

```
//create a count for rows here
inr rowNumber = 0;
//Here you are reading your list with all data readed
for(int i=0;i<arr.size()-1;i+=2){ //the -1 is for the array to stop on the 
                                 //last but one row

    row = spreadSheet.createRow((short) rowNumber); //external count

    //pseudocode from here
    cell1 = row.createCell(0); 
    cell2 = row.createCell(1); 

    cell1.setCellValue(  arr.get(i).substring(arr.get(i).indexOf(":")+1) );
                              // ^ this is for name
    cell2.setCellValue(  arr.get(i+1).substring(arr.get(i+1).indexOf(":")+1) );
                               // ^ this is for phone

    rowNumber++; //increment your rowNumber
}
```

Comment: Im new to programming i had to look up what pseudocode was :) im not sure about what external vs internal? count?

Comment: the external count is a variable that is defined outside the FOR and incremented inside it `rowNumber`. The internal count is the one used on the for, on this case it is `i`. Pseudocode is just a way to show how you should programm not a real sintaxe of the language, it is more like: do something, then test a variable, then sum the other variable then finalize the program.

Comment: This is my second project in java(That i want to finish) and is actually a real world program that can manipulate data. --------------------------------------------------So  I get cell creation in excel i have created cells no problem but the problem lies when i need to get the code from a text file. It wont line up with the spreadsheet. example, a1 b2 c3 as stated above. There has to be an easier way to write the code(maybe longer) so i can see whats going on. For example pseudocode: get first line from array(arr)>get only data after ":">create row and cell>input into cell only info after ":"

Comment: //String strLine;
 //String namepass[] = strLine.split(":"); 
 //String name = namepass[0]; 
 //String pass = namepass[1]; //ive been trying to get this code somehow into my code to its easier for me to understand? Am i on the right track? Thanks agian!

Comment: Yeah I choose to use substring because your string is pretty forward and is a pattern. always have the same values. If you want to use split you have to understand its working. let say you have this string: `a:b:c` when you use `String [] arr = "a:b:c".split(":")` on this passing `:` you are creating an string array with tree elements which is arr[0]=a; arr[1]=b and arr[2]=c on your question you read line by line which means that every line splitted you will have: arr[0]=Name and arr[1]= John doe (with the space) for the next line that has the phone it will be: arr[0]=phone and arr[1]=xxx-xxxx